# Android widget can't change background color

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, remoteview

I'm trying to change the background color of a `ListView` in an active widget on the fly like so,

```
public static void updateWidgetTheme(Context context, int bgColor) {
    RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    widget.setInt(R.id.listView, "setBackgroundColor", bgColor);
}
```

Which i'm calling from the Main activity of my app. There are active widgets. It seems to have no effect. I've read several questions where this is the appropriate way to change background color of a view in an active widget.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing your `RemoteViews` is not enough - you need to call [AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews)) with the `appWidgetId` and your updated `RemoteViews` to actually update the widget.

Comment: Yes just realized this. Thanks for accepted answer :)